# Vega-lite: How to show multiple "color" legends for multi-layer scatter plot?

Tags: vega-lite

My vega lite json: [Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQgpAE84AJzQBtUABMkmFKlAMNgtCANGCUJBohSZ8gL5Kc9pAgg7Qsr3CWZBo0eoogEHCCcFCYljSymJrESBZKTAlh6NCpcD4uALpKyBoA1pZQNBpQ0eFwslBseglkaKAAHm0gAGY0UVkgABJsDnA4bADumuGYqjiB6ACODEiJdIY0pCBuIKpdvf2WALI00RAA+vMa5wDiqYJyM3MLIMurmOsfWzuND1omPT6ggGw1G4ymWiUs3mljeayMX0CShytQBGlWZAW2hATEEDCROLxgQKLlJbn0hmMpnMlmsSFs9kc0keOxK5XQlWqtSU9UazVkrQBnQBB2Bx1OeUumlu90eUOesJW8I23yUexFQIGAEEoFAopoNnKQNCXnCPgjNoEfmw-vtNZYACI0CA4FR6hD1OLymFLJXmlUElELUDogVYwlIKDldJu8okskkoA)

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "grid",
          "select": "interval",
          "bind": "scales"
        }
      ],
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "Horsepower",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {
            "range": ["blue", "blue"]
          }
        }
      }
    },


    {
      "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "Miles_per_Gallon", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "Acceleration", "type": "quantitative"},
        "color": {
          "field": "Displacement",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {
            "range": ["black", "black"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm displaying 2 layers of scratter plot, so I want it to have 2 legend color bars.
When I use "color", the second legend is merged, and overriden by the first one.

When I change to use "fill", I manage to have 2 different color bars. But what if I have 4 layers, how to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `resolve` property.

```
 "resolve": {"legend":{"color": "independent"}, "scale": {"color": "independent"} }
```

[image]

Sample on vega editor:
[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQgpAE84AJzQBtUABMkmFKlAMNgtCANGCUJBohSZ8gL5Kc9pAgg7Qsr3CWZBo0eoogEHCCcFCYljSymJrESBZKTAlh6NCpcD4uALpKyBoA1pZQNBpQ0eFwslBseglkaKAAHm0gAGY0UVkgABJsDnA4bADumuGYqjiB6ACODEiJdIY0pCBuIKpdvf2WALI00RAA+vMa5wDiqYJyM3MLIMurmOsfWzuND1omPT6ggGw1G4ymWiUs3mljeayMX0CShytQBGlWZAW2hAExgInCGjgYQKLlJbn0hmMpnMlmsSFs9kc0keOxK5XQlWqtSU9UazVkrQBnQBB2Bx1OeUumlu90eUOesJW8I23yUexFQIGAEEoFAopoNnKQNCXnCPgjNoEfmw-vtNZYACI0CA4FR6hD1OLymFLJXmlVIiJ2VGgdECrE4vFJcJMN3lElKaKY2RZUAjPqJSyyOSBpP1PQADTQAGYAAylsmFJSEmSCLYAvMprq-EbxFNjfOe7bI4MLUAt-4gTId9uZslAA)